# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'length' was corrupted

Tags: c++, unicode, windows-runtime, runtime

> Hi All,
>
> I am working on changing our application to support unicode
>   characteristics . Hence while doing the changes i had to convert all
>   char to wchar_t and we had some wrapper stream classes which i
>   converted to support wchar_t . Now my issue is while doing the change
>   to the below code i encounter Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around
>   the variable 'length' was corrupted. though if i continue i get the
>   proper values . Please let me know how to get rid of this error.

```
FDIStream&  
FDIStream::
operator>>(std::wstring& data)
{
    if (CanReadData())
    {
        int length = -1;
        *this >> length;

        if (length >= 0)
        {
            // See if length is a valid value (not pass eof)
            if (length > GetLength()) {
                throw FDException("Corrupted file");
            }

            wchar_t* buffer = new wchar_t[length];

            try
            {
                ReadBytes(buffer, length);

                data = std::wstring(buffer,length); 
            } catch (...)
            {
                delete[] buffer;
                throw;
            }

            delete[] buffer;
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Let the debugger tell you.  Set a data breakpoint at `&length+1` and another one at `&length-1`.

Comment: +1 or -1 gives wrong values copied into data ... actually this copies perfectly the correct value ... "NO Core Embed"  and this passes the tests too but only issue is i am getting runtime check failure...

Comment: Google "what is a data breakpoint?"

Comment: I fixed the runtime error.  I rolled the stream code back to write out byte count and individual bytes.  The wide string streams now read in the byte count and adjust their character count using the byte count.  Streams need to have a consistent way of representing data, and character count would not work for wide strings since character count is not byte count.  .... thank you soo much Hans for all ur answers and support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the value of `length` as written to the stream by the producer was obtained via `data.length()` then it represents the number of *characters* in the string, not the number of bytes. I assume from it's name that `ReadBytes` is trying to `length` bytes, which is the problem. You need to read `length` characters.

Also, you're likely to have the mirrored bug in the producer if you are trying to write `length` bytes to the stream instead of `length` characters.

Comment: oid 
FDMemObject:: 
ReadBytes(void* data, int size) const
{
int actualSizeToRead = std::min(mLength - mPosition, size);
if (actualSizeToRead > 0) {
wchar_t* dataToCopy(const_cast (reinterpret_cast(data)));
std::wmemcpy(dataToCopy, mBuffer + mPosition, actualSizeToRead);
mPosition += actualSizeToRead;
}
 

FDIStream&
FDIStream:: 
operator>>(long& data)
{
if (CanReadData())
{
ReadBytes(&data, sizeof(data));
 
#if defined( __LITTLE_ENDIAN__)
data = FDCoreUtils::ConvertToFromBigEndianFormat(static_cast(data));
#endif
}
 
return *this;
}

Comment: I am passing byte value only ... which is 4 .... and while i am copying data to buffer ... buffer has "NO Embed Code" which should be the string in it and length 13 .... and after copying when i check the value of data ... i see it has 15 as size and it has "NO Embed Core" written into it .... Please let me know what actually is wrong with that code ...
 
I have doubt about that
Hide   Copy Code
data = FDCoreUtils::ConvertToFromBigEndianFormat(static_cast(data));
function as that has some byte manipluations it ...

Comment: inline char
FDLoByte(short value)
{
return static_cast(value & 0x000000FF);
}
 
inline int
FDHiWord(int value)
{
return (value >> 16) & 0x0000FFFF;
}
 
inline int
FDLoWord(int value)
{
return value & 0x0000FFFF;
}